# Edit Places in Gnome3

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel, places

EDIT: **This is a bug, read @jason's answer**

I try to customize the Places panel in Gnome3, but both `move` and `remove` options are grayed out. Also, I want to add folders to Places (NOT as bookmarks), but can't seem to find out how.

I know there are a lot of questions regarding bookmarks, but I want to be able to edit Places (since bookmarks isn't available through all application's file dialog)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a bug report you can follow and hope it gets fixed: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-panel/+bug/1070290

Answer (score 0):

Enter into the folder you want to bookmark, then click the cog wheel next to the exit, X button, where the options are, and click the option "add to bookmarks".